# I tried to scrape website which put in a .CSV file, what is the problem of my for loop in R?

Tags: r

I tried to scrape inf. from a list of websites(which is already be collected in a .csv file)
is there anything wrong of my for loop? I could scrape one website by the code alone, but when I put them in a loop, it couldn't generate results I want. Is the code right after 'for' correct? Below is the file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk1Ia.png)

```
library(rvest)
library(dbplyr)
setwd('/Users/wangye1/Desktop/ddl jan/009')
politico<-read.csv(file='politico.csv',header=T,sep=',')

website<-data.frame()
for(page_results in politico[1,45]){
    link="page_results"
  page=read_html(link)
  name=page%>%html_nodes("h1")%>%html_text()
  time=page%>%html_nodes("time")%>%html_text()
  tlinks=page%>%html_nodes("h1")%>%html_attr("href")%>%paste("http://www.politico.com/news/stories/0911",.,sep="")
  %>%paste("")
website=rbind(website,data.frame(name,time,tlinks)))
}
```

Comment: `politico[1,45]`  means the value from the first row and the 45th column.  You probably just want `politico[ ,1]`, the entire first column.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop can be corrected however, growing dataframes in a loop is very inefficient. You can use `lapply` or `map` functions from `purrr`.

```
library(rvest)

purrr::map_df(politico$URL, function(link) {
  page <- link %>% read_html()
  name= page %>%
    html_nodes("h1")%>%
    html_text()
  time= page %>%
    html_nodes("time") %>%
    html_text()
  tlinks = page %>%
    html_nodes("h1") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>% 
    paste0("http://www.politico.com/news/stories/0911",.)
  
  tibble(name, time, tlinks)
}) -> result

result
```

Comment: Hello! I tried to run it. it said--Error: Argument 1 must have names.

Comment: do we need to define what the link is here?